# Can a consumer (on a Microservice architecture using Masstransit) be a sender?

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, microservices, masstransit

!! Newbie ALERT in .net core!!
I have an authentication service with JWT and i want to send user info to a Product microservice in .net core 3.1.
i followed this ex : [Masstransit-Rabbitmq](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3q_cYsjJ2PM)

but the problem is when i receive the user data , i want to send back product data to the user service.

so my question is how can i establish a bidirectional communication between microservices in asp .net core 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a request and receive a response, you can use the request client. It's detailed properly in the documentation:

https://masstransit-project.com/usage/requests.html

> Request/response is a common pattern in application development, where a component sends a request to a service and continues once the response is received. In a distributed system, this can increase the latency of an application since the service may be hosted in another process, on another machine, or may even be a remote service in another network. While in many cases it is best to avoid request/response use in distributed applications, particularly when the request is a command, it is often necessary and preferred over more complex solutions.

Comment: so the communication between microservices can be done using only this Req/Res pattern ? (without using Rabbitmq nor Kafka or Azure Bus ?)

Comment: You still need a message broker supported by MassTransit, which performs the actual communication.